# Posting search query to GitHub in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, post, https

I need to create an Xcode app that will allow the user to post their input in the TextField and based on that will fetch GitHub repositories that match the query.

I can't even find a base URL for that GitHub API let alone, how to pass the input to the GitHub's search field.

Please help.

The idea of this app is to create a mobile GitHub repository search app that will deliver results based on the user's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub [api documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos) would be a good place to start looking. It tells you the endpoint to use, the responses and the parameters to query for the request.

To save you digging, hitting this endpoint will give you the repositories for the username you specify - which will be the input from the textField I assume.

```
https://api.github.com/users/YOUR_TEXTFIELD_INPUT/repos
```

Comment: Thanks :) I will check it out if the other method I'm trying now doesn't work.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to input the exact user name then though? The idea of this app is rather to create a mobile GitHub repository search app, @Owen.
The best solution would be to be able to POST queries to the search bar and GET the results back :)

Comment: @Swantewit In which case you could probably get away with using this endpoint - `https://api.github.com/repositories`. It's always good to specify what you're trying to achieve in the question too!

Comment: Thanks, @Owen, updated.